# unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'

Tags: bash, sql, here-string

I'm simply trying to get the output from a sql statement and store in bash variable. I am getting " unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'  " error. 
I don't see what i'm doing wrong. Why am I getting this error?

```
var=$($ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus / as sysdba <<EOF  
select status from v\$instance;
exit;
EOF
)
```

Comment: This is odd: your command works for me.

Comment: Check "bash --version" That "<< EOF" part requires Bash version -ge 4.1.

Comment: @MichaelD., seems to work for me on `version 3.1.17(1)-release`, as well as on 4.3.

Comment: @ilkkachu ok. my source was: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver4.html (Example 37-9. Using a here document to set a variable)

Answer (score 5):

Is your script indented like that? the delimiter for the here-doc has to be at the beginning of the line. This works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(cat <<EOF
blah
EOF
)
```

Comment: Good catch.  Note that [if you use `<<-EOF` instead of `<<EOF`,](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#Heredocs_And_Herestrings) any leading tab characters (but *not* leading spaces!) will be ignored—for the whole "heredoc," not just the delimiter.

Comment: it is not indented. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Ikkachu is correct that the code, when not indented, should work fine on any reasonably modern version of Bash. However, I would add that you may find it easier to understand and debug if you use a "here string" instead of a "here doc":

```
var=$(sqlplus / as sysdba <<< 'select status from v$instance; exit;')
```

Or, use a standard pipeline:

```
var=$(echo 'select status from v$instance; exit;' | sqlplus / as sysdba)
```